# How do I call hammer.js from the object declaration outside of the javascript code block?

Tags: javascript, html, hammer.js

I'm not sure if I asked this question correctly.  But with mouse events, I could put an onclick action in the object where I wanted the script to be called.  For example `<svg onclick="dosomefunction()"...>`  However, the hammer.js scripts are called differently.  It is passed an id from within the big block of the javascript.  I would like to have it work for every image on my page the same way that I could with mouse events.  Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
--Christopher

***Edit*** I'm adding the hammer call.
***2nd Edit ***  Modified the hammer function I posted earlier to add the event listener as suggested by the first commenter.

```
        var prevent_scroll_drag = true;
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
    var hammertime = [];

    for(i=0;i<element.length;i++){
    hammertime[i] = Hammer(element[i],{
          preventDefault: true,
        gesture: true
      }).on('doubletap drag pinch',
        function (event){
      switch(event.type){
        case 'doubletap':
          alert("doubletap");
          break;
        case 'drag':
          alert("drag");
          break;
        case 'pinch':
          alert("pinch");
          break;
      }//close switch
      }//function close
        );//closes .on() 
    }
```

Comment: use addEventListener() instead of inline events, then you just need a ref to the element to attach the event. the ref can come by passing, id, tag name, hierarchy path, etc

Comment: I'm still fairly new to javascript.  How do I addEventListener to every svg image in my document?

Comment: in a loop of document.getElementsByTagName("svg"), document.images, or by using one handler on the body and checking the e.target.tagName in that universal handler

Comment: I have the loop `var element = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
     var currentsvg;
     for(i=0;i<element.length;i++){
       currentsvg=element[i];
       element[i].addEventListener("doubletap drag pinch", initializeHammer(currentsvg) ,false);
     }`  However, I don't think it is doing anything.  I do not know how to pass the current svg to hammer touch functions.  I'll add the modifications to the original post

Comment: I managed to get the hammer.js to work on all svg images. I have edited my original post to show how I got it to work.  However, within the function called by the hammer routine, I do not know how to tell which svg is the active one.

Comment: I found that `this` does correctly identify the svg which activated the hammer.js routines.